# WSO2 - IBM MQ - javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to communicate with the queue manager while looking up object

Tags: wso2, jms, ibm-mq, esb

Facing the following issue while trying to connect WSO2 ESB proxy services to queues (newly created) configured in IBM MQ.

The strange part is, able to connect to queues which were already existing in the same Queue Manager, successfully.

```
TID: [0] [ESB] [2016-01-14 12:05:12,705]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener} -  Connection attempt: 1 for JMS Provider for service: UOFSInterface was successful! {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSListener}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2016-01-14 12:05:12,712]  INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager} -  Task manager for service : UOFSPickedInterface [re-]initialized {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager}
TID: [0] [ESB] [2016-01-14 12:05:12,829]  WARN {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSUtils} -  Cannot locate destination : UOFS.ESB.IN {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSUtils}
javax.naming.NamingException: Unable to communicate with the queue manager while looking up object UOFS.ESB.IN
        at com.ibm.mq.jms.context.MQContext.lookup(MQContext.java:947)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:411)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSUtils.lookup(JMSUtils.java:583)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.JMSUtils.lookupDestination(JMSUtils.java:789)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager.getDestination(ServiceTaskManager.java:950)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager.access$2700(ServiceTaskManager.java:50)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.createConsumer(ServiceTaskManager.java:905)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.getMessageConsumer(ServiceTaskManager.java:766)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.receiveMessage(ServiceTaskManager.java:516)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager$MessageListenerTask.run(ServiceTaskManager.java:428)
        at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
TID: [0] [ESB] [2016-01-14 12:05:12,833] ERROR {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager} -  Error creating JMS consumer for service : UOFSInterface. JMSWMQ2008: Failed to open MQ queue 'UOFS.ESB.IN'. {org.apache.axis2.transport.jms.ServiceTaskManager}
```

Comment: The error is suggesting to me that connectivity was lost to the QueueManager when looking up the object; is this a repeatable problem?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. This issue got fixed few minutes back. The queues didn´t have any permissions on them. Once appropriate access was provided the issue got fixed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The MQ client user profile used by the client system (WSO2) didn´t have the appropriate "authorities" like PUT, SET etc., to drop messages into the queue.

**The issue was resolved once the profile was given appropriate authorities to PUT, SET & BROWSE on the MQ queue object.**

Comment: This answer needs to be improved, even if a self-answer.